# Linux guest VM can't use host's OSX anyconnect VPN

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtualbox, vpn, cisco-vpn-client

I'm using cisco anyconnect to get into my work VPN, that on Mac OSX Lion.

I created a Xubuntu 12.10 VM in virtualbox and I can navigate the web while connected to the VPN in the OSX host, but I have no access at all to my work sites and services.

I've tried having the VM to use NAT and bridge for networking.

What's weird is that I have a similar setup in my office, have windows 7 as host being connected to the VPN with anyconnect client, and I have a Fedora 16 guest VM made with VMware, and that one just worked out of the box.

Any clues? thank you

Answer (score 1):

The configuration that works for me with the VPN (I use both SSTP and OpenConnect) installed on the host is to use NAT setting for the network adapter of the virtual machine. While using bridge you should have the VPN installed on the guest OS.

Are you sure it's not simply a matter of DNS/gateway setting on the guest OS? Have you tried to ping directly an IP address in your work network?

Answer (score 0):

AnyConnect does some fancy things under the hood, that's for sure. I still haven't really figured out exactly how it works. Have you tried to install the VPN client on the guest? If you don't have access to the Linux client, just use OpenConnect, it's in the repos.